# Ajax keep redirecting to the php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shopify

I have a shopify store and i want to add a form on product page the problem is when i want to submit a from using ajax with an external link but i want to stay on the same page it goes to the external link

```
<form method="post" id="fastform"action="http://website.fun/bianca/doc.php" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label  class="label" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Nom :  </label>
<input placeholder="Nom"    class="input" width="100%" type="text" name="nom" id="nom">
<label  class="label" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Télephone* :  </label>
<input placeholder="Telephone"    class="input" width="100%" type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
<input placeholder="Adresse"    class="input" width="100%" type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse">
<div id="form-messages"></div>
<button type="submit" class="button-input btn btn-default" name="btn"style="margin-top: 20px;" id="btn">Commander</button>
```

and this is the js en ajax part

```
<script>

$(function () {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#fastform');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
            }.done(function(response) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text("votre commande et bien traiter");

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        })).fail(function(data) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! il\'ya un problem');
            }
        });
                });
```

i want the page to stay without refreshing and get the results on the same page

Comment: Try to remove `action="http://website.fun/bianca/doc.php"` on your html form.

Comment: but want to handle the form on that page that exist on an external url

Comment: you can set the ajax url to `http://website.fun/bianca/doc.php` as string.

Comment: @abdessamadBen have you tried using onclick="return false" on the submit button

Comment: yes i tried it and the same problem

Comment: how about puttting your code in a function submitForm(){//code return false;}  and on the onclick="submitForm(); return false;"

Comment: There is a mistake in your js code. Add `)` right after `}` at row `}.done(function(response) {`, and delete a `)` at row `)).fail(function(data) {`

Comment: i fixed the js mistakes but still same problem

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$( "#your_form_id" ).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                //something to do before ajax call
            },
            complete: function () {
               //something to do after ajax call
            },
            type:"POST",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            url:"<?php echo $url;?>",
            success:function(data){
                $('#divId').html(data); // id where you want to retrive and show your data
            }
    });

});
```

Please review your action URL again

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Change the form like this.

```
<form method="post" id="fastform" onsubmit='return submitForm()' action="http://website.fun/bianca/doc.php" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And change the function like this,

```
  function submitForm(){

  var formData = $('#fastform').serialize();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $('#fastform').attr('action'),
      data: formData
  }.done(function(response) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
      $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
      $(formMessages).addClass('success');

      // Set the message text.
      $(formMessages).text("votre commande et bien traiter");

      // Clear the form.
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      $('#message').val('');
  })).fail(function(data) {
      // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
      $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
      $(formMessages).addClass('error');

      // Set the message text.
      if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
      } else {
          $(formMessages).text('Oops! il\'ya un problem');
      }
  });

  return false;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the respond but still the same problem by the way i'm working on shopify web site  and i'm editing the product page but i saw many people done that on the stores

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function (){ 
 $('form').bind('submit', function () { 
       $.ajax({ type: 'post', 
        url: 'libs/send.php', 
        data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
        cache: false, 
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () { 
      alert("Data has been successfully inserted"); 
   } 
    }); 
   return false; 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: same problem i think something wrong with shopify i'm sending the request from ajax and it's sends without using it

Comment: ok,
Can you try this code:
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#addcate").submit(function(e){ var data1=$('#data1').val(); var data=$('#data').val(); $.ajax({  url: "libs/send.php", method:"post",  data: {data1:data1, data:data},  success:function(response){   alert(response); } }); }); });